# Is It Possible to Have a Slow Query In Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read in the documentation that the amount of time for retreiving data will be the same for querying a collection of 6 documents and a collection of 60M.

So is it safe to save all of the data of a specific kind (like users) under the same collection? Will I never have to split them into separate collections for getting better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to have slow-performing queries on Firestore, but the performance will not be related to the number of documents in the collection that you're querying. A common cause of slow reads is for example having documents that contain way more data than the application needs, which means that it takes more time to download that data to the client than is necessary for the use-case.

In your example: it is indeed normal to store all user profiles in a single collection. Querying 6 users out of that collection will always take the same amount of time, even if you app grows to millions or hundreds of millions of users.